# why there isn't some NodeID in NodeCallback

Tags: visual-c++, cplex

I got NodeID(getNodeID) and Parent from BranchCallback and got variable branch from NodeCallback. When I draw tree search algorithm, some nodes there isn't any variable branch before those nodes and when I saw the console of VS C++ there isn't any record for those NodeId. But I am sure that there are many information like objective value for those nodes in BranchCallback.why is that?[image]

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking and how you obtain the information you have. can you please show all the relevant parts of your code? How exactly you obtain all the information you have and how you relate the different pieces of information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that (as I explained in another post) the NodeID displayed in the console log is different from the NodeID you obtain in a callback. So these two things can not be related.

Then, for the other things you are asking it is not clear how you obtain any of the data. In particular, if you collect nodes in a branch callback and then only later figure our the branching variable in a node callback then this may not work for nodes that were pruned. Why not get the branching variable from the branch callback as well?
Here is an easy example how to do that:

```
#include <map>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
#include <ilcplex/ilocplex.h>
#include <ilconcert/ilothread.h>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

/** The info we collect for a node. */
struct Info {
   IloCplex::MIPCallbackI::NodeId id;        /**< The node's id. */
   IloCplex::MIPCallbackI::NodeId parent;    /**< ID of the parent (root is 0). */
   IloNumVar                      branchVar; /**< The variable on which CPLEX branched
                                              * to create this node. */
   IloNum                         branchVal; /**< The value CPLEX used for branching. */
   IloCplex::BranchDirection      branchDir; /**< The direction into which CPLEX branched. */
};

// Overload operator< so that we can use NodeIds as keys in maps.
bool operator<(IloCplex::MIPCallbackI::NodeId const &n1,
               IloCplex::MIPCallbackI::NodeId const &n2)
{
   return n1._id < n2._id;
}

// Map node ids to Info objects so that you can easily get from the info
// for a child to the info of its parent.
IloFastMutex lck;
typedef std::map<IloCplex::MIPCallbackI::NodeId,Info> MapType;
MapType nodeMap;

// A simple branch callback that tracks CPLEX branching decisions.
ILOBRANCHCALLBACK0(BranchCallback) {
   IloInt const n = getNbranches();
   IloCplex::MIPCallbackI::NodeId me = getNodeId();
   IloNumVarArray x(getEnv());
   IloNumArray bounds(getEnv());
   IloCplex::BranchDirectionArray dirs(getEnv());
   for (IloInt b = 0; b < n; ++b) {
      // Get what CPLEX plans to do and perform the exact same branch.
      // Then record all the information abouth the newly created branch.
      getBranch(x, bounds, dirs, b);
      Info info;
      info.id = makeBranch(b);
      info.parent = me;
      if ( x.getSize() == 1 ) {
         info.branchVar = x[0];
         info.branchVal = bounds[0];
         info.branchDir = dirs[0];
      }
      else {
         // CPLEX branches on more than one variable. We don't record that.
         info.branchVar = 0;
         info.branchVal = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
         info.branchDir = IloCplex::BranchGlobal;
      }
      lck.lock();
      nodeMap.insert(MapType::value_type(info.id, info));
      lck.unlock();
   }
   dirs.end();
   bounds.end();
   x.end();
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv) {
   for (int a = 1; a < argc; ++a) {
      IloEnv env;
      IloModel model(env);
      IloCplex cplex(model);
      cplex.importModel(model, argv[a]);
      cplex.use(BranchCallback(env));
      nodeMap.clear();
      cplex.setParam(IloCplex::Threads, cplex.getNumCores());
      //cplex.setParam(IloCplex::Threads, 1);
      //cplex.setParam(IloCplex::NodeLim, 10);
      cplex.solve();

      // Print information about all the nodes.
      for (MapType::const_iterator it = nodeMap.begin(); it != nodeMap.end(); ++it) {
         Info const &i = it->second;
         cout << "Node " << i.id << " created from " << i.parent
              << " by branching "
              << (i.branchDir == IloCplex::BranchUp ? "up" : "down")
              << " on " << (i.branchVar.getImpl() ? i.branchVar.getName() : "more than one variable")
              << " with value " << i.branchVal
              << endl;
      }
      env.end();
   }
   return 0;
}
```

If you also want to trace the order in which the nodes are selected then add a field

```
   IloInt order;
```

to the `Info` class and use a node callback like this one:

```
// A simple node callback that tracks the order in which nodes are selected.
ILONODECALLBACK0(NodeCallback) {
   // The order that CPLEX plans to execute next is at index 0.
   IloCplex::MIPCallbackI::NodeId next = getNodeId(0);
   lck.lock();
   static IloInt order = 0;
   nodeMap[next].order = order++;
   lck.unlock();
}
```

(instead of a simple counter you can use a timestamp or something else as well).